# Unordered list page-break-inside:avoid not working and overlap with footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a page with header, footer and main content. The main content consists of Bootstrap 4 card list groups.

I am trying to make a printable version of the list. Expected result is list elements to not break between pages. However, the page-break-inside: avoid is not working and the content is overlapping with the footer.

Screenshot and code as below:
[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUbX.png)

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

main {
  padding-top: 24pt;
  padding-bottom: 48pt;
}

@media print {
  li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Card</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
          <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
          <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
          <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
          <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h5 class="card-title">Title </h5>
          <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <td>Value</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem recently. Turns out that `display:flex;` does not play very well with Chrome's printing layout. In my case, it was a list-group and Bootstrap has `.list-group {display: flex; }` so to fix I set simply used:

```
@media print {
  .list-group {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

And then `list-group-item {page-break-inside: avoid; }` to avoid page-breaks inside the list items!

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked for page-break-after and page-break-before in Chrome and Firefox.